# High notes on trumpet, sound stuck in my throat

Tags: technique, trumpet

I'm a french trumpet player. I have been practising a lot on my trumpet lately and I am making improvements. But everytime I try to get to high notes, the sound is "stuck" in my throat.

However, when I take my mouthpiece and vibrate in it, I can go really high. And I can use the right amount of air! But the moment I grab my trumpet and play high, the sound disapears in my throat, as if it was really tight and tense.

I'm desperate to get better, but I always struggle with anxiety and muscular problems, my muscles are always really tense. I imagine that all I should do is to relax my throat for the air to keep going, but I can't.

Do you know how I could relax my throat, and letting the air come along with my lips? Do you know any exercices to be more "relaxed" while holding the trumpet? It is really important to me. I started to get really depressed by the fact that everything is improving except for my range.

Comment: I would try to see a teacher to exclude tension in the wrong parts of the body. I was astonished to read *throat* since I see no required interaction with the stream of air. Have you tried another trumpet with the same effect?

Comment: Interestingly,  Merriam-Webster defines "french trumpet" as "an organ reed stop of 8′ pitch and brilliant tone"

Comment: I actually never tried another trumpet. I just have my own !

Answer (score 1):

I would play lip slurs/trills between B and G while holding valves 1 and 3 down going as fast as I can and this should make your range and endurence better.

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing to do is work with a teacher.

Aside from that, I would recommend playing long tones, starting with the 4 or 5 pitches at the top of your current comfortable range, and adding one or two pitches above that. Concentrate on not changing your throat or diaphragm muscles.
Along with the long tones,  play a slow slurred scale going up, concentrating on a continuous clean sound. This will help you "forget" that you've just gone a pitch or two higher than you thought comfortable.

And be patient -- it may take quite a while to add, say, a full octave to your range.

Comment: Thanks you, I will follow your advices ! I can feel, indeed, that a part of the problem is the fact that I might be "afraid" of getting highter.